# Deploying a django rest framework api that uses react for the frontend

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, deployment, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a project that that has a react frontend from which I fetch information from the rest framework api and then display it. It is the first time I deploy something like this and I have found it very confusing to understand what is the best way to deploy this.

### What I Have Tried

I tried deploying on heroku without really knowing what I was doing and then the following happened.
My react app shows perfectly on heroku without any problems, but when the fetch funcitons are called there was an error that said connection refused. Then I realized that my django server had to be running in my computer in order to react o be able to fetch the information.

I thought that the django server would also get deployed but apparently I have to deploy separately I guess.

I have been searching for a while and I found something about nginx, digital ocean and docker but I didn't understand what would I have to do in this case.

Anyone knows what should do I do in this case?

Comment: You should rewrite the question to be about something specific. For example, you could ask why the error is happening (be sure to include the error message). Otherwise I'm not sure there's much to help with. This is kind of a "How do I use Heroku"/"How do I deploy in the cloud" question and there's really no way to answer that. I would suggest following a Heroku tutorial for deploying a Rails or Node server, and then trying to do the same thing for Django

Comment: Oh okay thank you it is just I am new to this and I don't really know how to use stackoverflow. I will trying searching for the tutorials, thank you!

Comment: The boilerplate with tutorial on how to deploy Django+React with Docker-Compose https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/

Comment: Oh that is perfect thank you!